# Ramanujan-type sum

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Could you show that
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{k}{e^{\frac{\pi  k}{2}}+1}=\frac{7 \pi ^2+6 \left(\psi _{e^{2 \pi }}^{(1)}(1)+\psi _{e^{2 \pi }}^{(1)}\left(1-\frac{i}{2}\right)-\psi _{e^{2 \pi }}^{(1)}\left(1+\frac{i}{4}\right)-\psi _{e^{2 \pi }}^{(1)}\left(1-\frac{i}{4}\right)\right)}{24 \pi ^2}$$ using the Mellin transform?

Comment: Needs more context, ilke what is $\psi$ etc.

Comment: Why specifically "using the Mellin transform"?  Is this part of an exercise statement, or do you already have a proof by other approach?

Comment: Do you mean a sum type involving [`q-Pochhammer symbol`](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/96223/q-pochhammer-symbol-identity) identities maybe?

Comment: Dear Mr Noam I could calculate some types of this type sum ,theset are related to elliptic integrals and try to calculate some of these values..

Answer (score 1):

If we formally apply Abel–Plana's summation formula (see, for example, http://www.jstor.org/stable/2008442):
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty f(k)=\frac{1}{2}f(0)+\int\limits_0^\infty f(x)dx+i\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{f(ix)-f(-ix)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx,$$
we get
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k}{e^{\frac{\pi}{2}k}+1}\;?=?\;
\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{x}{e^{\frac{\pi}{2}x}+1}dx-\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{x}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{24}=7/24.$$
Similarly, in the case of [Ramanujan sum type](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/238841/ramanujan-sum-type) we get 
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k}{e^{2k}+1}\;?=?\;
\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{x}{e^{2x}+1}dx-\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{x}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{48}-\frac{1}{24}.$$
Numerically it seems we got almost correct results (in the first case relative accuracy is about $10^{-4}$ and in the second case about $10^{-3}$). Why Abel–Plana's summation formula cannot be applied in these cases and how it can be amended to produce correct results?

As for the Mellin transform method, the following references might be useful: 
http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/14786444908521717 (The application of Mellin Transforms to the summation of slowly convergent series, by G.G. Macfarlane) and http://www.scielo.org.ve/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0254-07702010000100011 (A summation formula concerning the Mellin Transform, by M.L. Glasser, N. Bagis and 
G. Majchrowska).

P.S. Abel–Plana's summation formula cannot be applied in these cases because $f(z)$ is not bounded in the right-half complex plane.

$\psi_q^{(n)}$ is, I think, $q$-Polygamma Function: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html

Similar sum $$\sum\limits_{k=1,3,5,...}^\infty \frac{k}{e^{k\pi}+1}=\frac{1}{24}$$ is calculated by the Mellin transform method in the answer to the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389146/proof-of-frac1e-pi1-frac3e3-pi1-frac5e5-pi1-ldots/389168#389168  See also the answer to the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482918/evaluating-sum-n-1-infty-fracn3e2-pi-n-1-using-inverse-mellin-tra where the sum 
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^5}{e^{2\pi k}-1}=\frac{1}{504}$$ is calculated (I found these links thanks to Antonio's comment).

Comment: Dear Mr Zurab good explanation but this integral it is difficul to resolve anyway the second sum it is possible calculate as $$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{k}{1-e^{\frac{\pi  k}{2}}}=\frac{6 \psi _{e^{4 \pi }}^{(1)}(1)+6 \psi _{e^{4 \pi }}^{(1)}\left(1-\frac{i}{4}\right)-\pi ^2-48 \pi }{24 \pi ^2}-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{\pi }$$